# How do I install Asterisk on Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra?

Tags: macos, asterisk

I have been successfully installed and run Asterisk 13 with bcg729 on Mac OS X 10.10, is there a way to install Asterisk 15 with g729 on latest MacOS X?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build via Homebrew and start Asterisk 15 w/g729 codec on

- Asterisk 15.1.5 + bcg729
- Mac OS X High Sierra v10.13.4
- Mac mini (Late 2012) 2.5GHz Intel Core i5 16GB DDR3

## Steps for Asterisk 15 w/bcg729 on Mac OS X High Sierra v10.13.4

1. minor issues in asterisk.rb and pjsip-asterisk.rb during brew
2. change "<<-EOS.undent" to "<<~EOS" as suggest by brew solve the problem

-

```
#Homebrew
xcode-select --install
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"    

#git, mercurial
brew install git mercurial

#asterisk
brew tap leedm777/homebrew-asterisk
brew install asterisk

#bcg729
/usr/local/bin/git clone git://git.linphone.org/bcg729.git
cd bcg729
git checkout 1.0.2
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install

#asterisk-g729
/usr/local/bin/hg clone http://bitbucket.org/arkadi/asterisk-g72x
cd asterisk-g72x
./autogen.sh 
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-bcg729 --with-asterisk150
make
make install

#start asterisk
brew services start leedm777/asterisk/asterisk
```